# How will the SVN status boxes appear in Xcode project navigator?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

How will the SVN status boxes appear in Xcode project navigator?
After successfully checking out from svn, it should ideally show me Modified or added files but its not.

Does anybody know how to enable them. thnks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select 'Show Remote Status' & 'Show Working Copy Status' from File->Source Control

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your project is properly configured to use a svn repository?

Comment: All the new files are seen on project navigator but no boxes along with them.

Comment: buddy im not sure about many things in life but this I'm sure :)